# Chlorine gas and stainless steel

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

After dealing with a leak from a 73 kg compressed chlorine gas cylinder at 6 bar, there was green powder/rust/discoloration on the stainless steel tubing similar to copper chloride or copper sulphate. Any thoughts of what this might be?

Comment: It is likely to be compounds of the main elements in stainless steel: Ni, Cr and Fe. Special alloys are often used when corrosive gas exposure is expected, e.g., Monel. In your case, the exposure was accidental.

Comment: Thanks Ed V ,  but would any of these have the chractrustic blue/green of Copper Chloride/sulphate ?

Comment: All three of the metals have some green compounds. There are numerous varieties of stainless steels, e.g., 316 and 304, but I don’t know what stainless steel you are dealing with. I will check to see if I can find the colors of the chlorides of Ni, Cr, and Fe. But I am guessing someone here will post an actual helpful answer. If I find anything useful, I will post as a comment. If an actual helpful answer is posted by someone, I will delete my comments: I think (I am still new here) that comments are supposed to go away sooner rather than later.

Comment: BTW, some stainless steels that are resistant to *dry* chlorine are attacked by *moist* Cl2, so check for any water in the environment.

Comment: From wiki, the hydrated chlorides are various greens. Also, wiki says HCl attacks all varieties of stainless steel and contact should be avoided. I know this is correct from my lab experience. When chlorine gas encounters water vapor in the air, some HCl gas is formed, so I think you have some hydrated chlorides. Hope this helps!

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik Excellent point! Sadly, though, my lab environments were never dry! When it rained hard, I even had rain in one of my hoods!

Comment: I will post some images tomorrow to illustrate - but thanks for the I input so far 